# Check for the existence of term slug

Tags: slug

I need to check term slug, if slug do not have, not display:

```
 if(is_tax()){
  $permalink = get_home_url() ."/category" . '/' .$term_slug . '/' .$post->post_name;
}else{
  $permalink = get_home_url() ."/univer/". $post->post_name;
}
```

UPD:

I need get something like this:

when I click on post name in category, in browser should be url:
domain/categoryname/postname

when I click on custom taxonomy, in browser should be url:
domain/taxname/postname

for other pages like this:
domain/custom_post_type/postname

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/382746/edit) to add more details. What have you tried? What *specific* problem are you having?

Comment: And why are you hard-coding the permalink - there are functions like [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) to properly get a category permalink.

Comment: @PatJ added update what i need, thank you for the help